# TouchImageView for resetview

Tags: android, image, pinchzoom

I am new to android. I am developing an app of wallpapers. I am using 2 buttons to change the image.the images are changinging nicely. And using TouchImageView class to zoom in or out these images. With this class images are zooming in and out. But the problem is that when I zoom in image (for example to 2f) and click the next button to change the image then current image shown from 2f zoomed , not from the base. The next image should displayed from its base (for example 1f).So plz help me to solve this problem. Here is my TouchImageView class.

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
Matrix matrix; 
// We can be in one of three states
static int NONE=0;
static int DRAG=1;
static int ZOOM=2;
int mode=NONE;
// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF ();
PointF last = new PointF ();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 2f;
float[] m;
int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f; 
protected float origWidth, origHeight; 
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;
ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector; 
Context context; 
public TouchImageView (Context context) {
super (context);
sharedConstructing ( context ); 
}
public TouchImageView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
super ( context, attrs ); 
sharedConstructing ( context ); 
}
public void resetView () {
// we can be in one of three states
NONE = 0;
DRAG = 1;
ZOOM = 2;
mode = NONE;
// Remember some things for zooming
last = new PointF ( ); 
start= new PointF ( ); 
minScale = 1f;
maxScale = 2f;
CLICK =3;
saveScale = 1f; 
matrix = new Matrix ();
m = new float [ 9 ]; 
setImageMatrix ( matrix ); 
setScaleType ( ScaleType.MATRIX ); 
}
private void sharedConstructing ( Context context ) {
Super.setClickable (true);
this.context = context; 
mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector ( context, new ScaleListener ());
matrix = new Matrix ();
m = new float [ 9 ]; 
setImageMatrix ( matrix ); 
setScaleType ( ScaleType.MATRIX ); 
setOnTouchListener ( new OnTouchListener ( ) {
@Override
public boolean OnTouch (View v, MotionEvent event ) {
mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent ( event ); 
PointF curr = new PointF ( event.getX ( ), event.getY ( ) ); 
switch ( event.getAction ( ) ) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
last.set ( curr);
start.set ( last ); 
mode = DRAG; 
break; 
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
if ( mode = = DRAG ) {
float deltaX = curr.x - last.x; 
float deltaY = curr.y - last.y; 
float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans (deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale ); 
float FixTransY = getFixDragTrans (deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale ); 
matrix.postTranslate (fixTransX, fixTransY);
fixTrans ();
last.set ( curr.x, curr.y ); 
}
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
mode = NONE; 
int xDiff = ( int ) Math.abs ( curr.x - start.x ); 
int yDiff = ( int ) Math.abs ( curr.y - start.y ); 
if ( xDiff < CLICK & & yDiff < CLICK ) performClick ( ); 
break; 
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP :
mode = NONE; 
break; 
}
setImageMatrix ( matrix ); 
invalidate ( ); 
return true; 
// indicate event was handled
}
});
}
public void setMaxZoom ( float x ) {
maxScale = x; 
}
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
@Override
public boolean onScaleBegin ( ScaleGestureDetector detector ) {
mode = ZOOM; 
return true; 
}
@Override
public boolean onScale ( ScaleGestureDetector detector ) {
float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor ( ); 
float origScale = saveScale; 
saveScale * = mScaleFactor; 
if ( saveScale > maxScale ) {
saveScale = maxScale; 
mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale; 
} else if ( saveScale < minScale ) {
saveScale = minScale; 
mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale; 
}
if ( origWidth * saveScale < = viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale < = viewHeight) matrix.postScale ( mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2 ); 
else matrix.postScale ( mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY ( ) ); 
fixTrans ();
return true; 
}
}
void FixTrans () {
matrix.getValues ( m ); 
float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X ]; 
float transY = m [ Matrix.MTRANS_Y ]; 
float fixTransX = getFixTrans (transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale ); 
float fixTransY = getFixTrans (transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale ); 
if ( FixTransX! = 0 || fixTransY! = 0) matrix.postTranslate ( fixTransX, fixTransY);
}
float getFixTrans (float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize){
float minTrans, maxTrans;
if ( contentSize <= viewSize) {
minTrans = 0;
maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize; 
} else {
minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
maxTrans = 0;
}
if ( trans < minTrans) return -trans + minTrans;
if (trans > maxTrans) return - trans + maxTrans; 
return 0;
}
float getFixTrans (float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
if ( contentSize <= viewSize) {
return 0;
}
return delta;
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure ( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec ) {
super.onMeasure ( widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec ); 
viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize ( widthMeasureSpec ); 
viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize ( heightMeasureSpec ); 
// Rescaled image on rotation
if ( oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
return; 
OldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight; 
oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth; 
if ( saveScale == 1) {
// Fit to screen
float scale; 
Drawable drawable = getDrawable ();
if ( drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth () == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight () == 0)
return; 
int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth ();
int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight ();
Log.d ("bmSize", "bmWidth:" + bmWidth + " bmHeight:" + bmHeight);
float scaleX = ( float ) viewWidth / ( float ) bmWidth; 
float scaleY = ( float ) bmHeight / ( float ) bmHeight; 
scale = Math.min ( scaleX, scaleY ); 
matrix.setScale ( scale, scale ); 
// Center the image
float redundantYSpace = ( float ) viewHeight - ( scale * ( float ) bmHeight ); 
float redundantXSpace = ( float ) viewWidth - ( scale * ( float ) bmWidth ); 
origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace; 
origHeight = viewHeight -2 * redundantYSpace; 
setImageMatrix ( matrix ); 
}
fixTrans ();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the latest version of Touchimageview.

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView
set this variable to false.